# .dwg import into QGIS in mm issue

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dwg

When importing a dwg into qgis with the unit set to mm it's not in the wrong place. If I switch the units to M it's in the correct place. The problem seems to be with the coordinates being off, 425166415 when in mm, and 425166.415 (which is correct) when in M.

Can anyone advise on how I can avoid this when being sent drawings in the future, without the need to convert the drawing into M and scale it using AutoCAD LT or equivalent?

Comment: Do you mean that the mm value is actually in centimeters?  4251664.15 m is chancing into 425166415 mm, while the correct value is 4251664150 mm. Is this your problem?

Comment: sorry - bad decimal point

Comment: I guess that QGIS awaits that the units in the DWG are the same than those that are used in the coordinate system. So the workaround could be to create a custom coordinate system that is using millimeters as units. How to do it is maybe changed after this bug report https://issues.qgis.org/issues/9414. If you need to import into some standard CRS then I would try to import first and then scale the coordinates by 1000 with the Affine transform tool.